# UITableView not displaying cells

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, xcode6

I am using Xcode 6 Swift and storyboards to build an IOS app. Bellow is what I have in my File.swift:

```
import Foundation

struct December {
    let name : String
}
```

Then, in my view controller, I have:

```
import UIKit

class ViewControllerDecember: UITableViewController {

    var december = [December] ()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        self.december = [December(name: "1"), December(name: "2"), December(name: "3"), December(name: "4"), December(name: "5"), December(name: "6"), December(name: "7"), December(name: "8"), December(name: "9"), December(name: "10"), December(name: "11"), December(name: "12"), December(name: "13"), December(name: "14"), December(name: "15"), December(name: "16"), December(name: "17"), December(name: "18"), December(name: "19"), December(name: "20"), December(name: "21"), December(name: "22"), December(name: "23"), December(name: "24"), December(name: "25"), December(name: "26"), December(name: "27"), December(name: "28"), December(name: "29"), December(name: "30"), December(name: "31")]

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.december.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var de1 : December

        de1 = december[indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = de1.name

        return cell


    }
}
```

When I run the app, it displays the table view but none of the cell data. What am I missing?

Comment: Have you implemented the method that informs the tableView how many sections it has?

Comment: @stevesliva How do I do that? This is my first time trying to do any coding.

Comment: @stevesliva how do I do that?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/numberOfSectionsInTableView:

Comment: Did you ever set the pointer to the dataSource?

Comment: @HotLicks I did not, what you see is what I have.

Comment: @HotLicks He doesn't need to. `VieControllerDecember` subclasses from `UITableViewController`. It has itself as the datasource. @OwenBridges Do you have any prototype cells with identifier `cell` in the storyboard?

Comment: One more point is that you can reduce the code you use to set `self.december` to this `self.december = (1...31).map { December(name: toString($0)) }`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may simply need to set the prototype cell identifier to "cell".

Go to the storyboard, click on your tableview, click on the attributes.

Give yourself a prototype cell by changing it from 0 to 1.

Click on the prototype cell.  Set the 'identifier' attribute to "cell".

Answer (score 0):

For me, I was confused by not displaying of tableview unless you swipe the screen. and finally I found lack of statement: `reloadDate()`

```
Query.FindinBackGround(...)
self.mytableview.reloadDate()
```